# Grails services and Spring task scheduling

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a Grails 2.0.1 webappp which should run some task each couple of hours. I'm using Spring's integrated task scheduling to make this happen so I don't need yet another plugin.

However, when I'm trying to do anything with the database, like save a model, I get the following error message:

> Message: No signature of method: rssreader.Feed.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>   Possible solutions: save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), wait(), any(), wait(long)

With the following code:

```
@Transactional
class FeedRefresherService {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000L)
    public void madeUpMethod() {
        def feed = new Feed()
        feed.title = "Test feed"
        feed.save()
    }
}
```

I believe this has something to do with the GORM methods not being available because of the scheduling, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.
Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: if it was because of GORM methods not being available, I think you wouldn't see save methods listed as possible solutions.

Comment: I guess @Scheduled annotation is not supported in grails. http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8921

Answer (score 0):

I think your Hibernate Session got "disconnected" I have faced similar error in past, but do not remember how I resolved it...:(

For task scheduling you could use [quartz plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz) which is quite stable, I have been using it in production for quite some time. Take a look at the source code of the [Executor plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/executor) which deals with associating hibernate sessions with multiple threads, while it may not solve your problem, it might give you a lead on how to tackle it.